# ASP.Net Identity with old Membership-tables

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I'm using Forms Based AUthentication with SharePoint.
It uses the following tables :
[image]

Now I'm using the ASP.Net identity framework and this uses the following tables :
[image]

How can I make the ASP.Net identity work with the "SharePoint"-tables?

Comment: I've tried changing the mapping:

Comment: Move to a db-first solution and just import your other tables.